# How to install data_files to absolute path?

Tags: python, pip

I use pip with setuptools to install a package. 
I want pip to copy some resource files to, say, `/etc/my_package`.

My `setup.py` looks like this:

```
setup(
    ...
    data_files=[('/etc/my_package', ['config.yml'])]
)
```

When running `pip install`, the file ends up in

```
~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/etc/my_package/config.yml
```

instead of `/etc/my_package`.

What am I doing wrong?

(pip version 9.0.1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: use `pip install --no-binary :all:` to install your package.

I struggled with this for a while and eventually figured out that there is some weirdness/inconsistency in how `data_files` are handled between binary wheels and source distributions. Specifically, there is a bug with wheels that makes *all* paths in `data_files` relative to the install location (see https://github.com/pypa/wheel/issues/92 for an issue tracking this).

"Thats fine", you might say, "but I'm not using a wheel!". Not so fast! It turns out recent versions of pip (I am working with 9.0.1) will try to compile a wheel even from a source distribution. For example, if you have a package `my_package` you can see this doing something like

```
$ python setup.py sdist   # create source tarball as dist/my_package.tar.gz
              [...]
$ pip install dist/my_package.tar.gz # install the generated source
              [...]
Building wheels for collected packages: my_package
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for my_package ... done
```

`pip` tries to be helpful and build a wheel to install from and cache for later. This means you will run into the above bug even though in theory you are not using `bdist_wheel` yourself. You can get around this by running `python setup.py install` directly from the package source folder. This avoids the building and caching of built wheels that `pip` will try to do but is majorly inconvenient when the package you want is already on PyPI somewhere. Fortunately `pip` offers an option to explicitly disable binaries.

```
$ pip install --no-binary :all: my_package
              [...]
Skipping bdist_wheel for my_package, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: my_package
  Running setup.py install for my_package ... done
Successfully installed my_package-0.1.0
```

Using the `--no-binary` option prevents wheel building and lets us reference absolute paths in our `data_files` paths again. For the case where you are installing a lot of packages together and want to selectively disable wheels you can replace `:all:` with a comma separated list of packages.

Comment: This doesn't work for me anymore nowadays, The other options `--no-cache-dir` and `--use-feature=no-binary-enable-wheel-cache` don't do anything for me.

Answer (score 4):

it seems that data_files can't support absolute path, it will add sys.prefix before "/etc/my_package", if you want to put config.yml to ../site_packages/my_package, please try:

```
import os
import sys
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
relative_site_packages = get_python_lib().split(sys.prefix+os.sep)[1]
date_files_relative_path = os.path.join(relative_site_packages, "my_package")
setup(
...
data_files=[(date_files_relative_path, ['config.yml'])]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing an `init()` function that installs the config file on first run instead of creating it during the installation:

```
def init():
    try:
        if not path.isdir(config_dir): 
            os.mkdir(cs_dir)
            copyfile(pkg_resources.resource_filename(
                               __name__, "default_config.yml"), config_file)
            print("INFO: config file created. ")
    except IOError as ex:
        print("ERROR: could not create config directory: " + str(ex)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
    main()
```